# How to get a query array inside a query array in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, google-bigquery

I have a table that stores **Stock** as JSON data type.

I need to write a query that returns the ProductID and Quantity in this output format:

[image]

However the most close to it I managed to do is this output:

```sql
SELECT

  GenerationTime
  JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(Stock.Sellable) Stock_Sellable_ProductID
  ,OrganizationUnit.IsDeleted OrganizationUnit_IsDeleted
  ,OrganizationUnit.Description OrganizationUnit_Description
  ,OrganizationUnit.BranchNumber
  ,OrganizationUnit.BranchNumber
  
FROM
  `....xt_...stock`
  
where GenerationTime = timestamp("2022-08-09 01:00:28.169503 UTC")
```

[image]

I also managed to use UNNEST but this will repeat the GenerationTime four times:

```sql
SELECT

  GenerationTime
  ,s.ProductID
  ,OrganizationUnit.IsDeleted OrganizationUnit_IsDeleted
  ,OrganizationUnit.Description OrganizationUnit_Description
  ,OrganizationUnit.BranchNumber
  ,OrganizationUnit.BranchNumber
  
FROM
  `....xt_...stock`
  left join unnest(JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(Stock.Sellable)) s
where GenerationTime = timestamp("2022-08-09 01:00:28.169503 UTC")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider below query:

```sql
SELECT (SELECT AS STRUCT
               ARRAY_AGG(STRING(s.ProductID) ORDER BY o) AS ProductID,
               ARRAY_AGG(INT64(s.Quantity) ORDER BY o) AS Quantity
          FROM UNNEST(JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(Stock.Sellable)) s WITH OFFSET o
       ) AS sellable
  FROM xt_stock;
```

[image]